# Insert a String into an other String

Tags: java

How can i add a line of String into the main String. The main String contains multiple lines of text. I want to add a new line to the third line and push backwards the rest of the main String.

Answer (score 4):

Direct concatenation is the simplest way to write this:

```
string = string.substring(0, position) + newData + string.substring(position);
```

where `position` is the location at which you want to insert the data, found e.g. using `indexOf`:

```
int position = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
  position = string.indexOf('\n', position + 1);
}
```

An alternative to direct concatenation:

```
string = new StringBuilder(string)
    .insert(position, newData)
    .toString();
```

Or (*perhaps* more efficient):

```
string = new StringBuilder(string.length() + newData.length())
    .append(string, 0, position)
    .append(newData)
    .append(string, position, string.length())
    .toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Split into a list, insert into list, then join list.

```
List<String> lines = new ArrayList(string.split('\n'))
lines.add(2, newLine)
String newString = lines.join('\n')
```

or

Get the position of the 3rd line, then use `substring`

```
string.substring(0, insertPos) + '\n' + newString +  string.substring(insertPos, string.length())
```

Comment: The final `string.length` should be `string.length()`; but in any case can be omitted.

Comment: @AndyTurner Thanks.  Too much Kotlin these days.  Anyway I added a better approach.

Comment: "I added a better approach" not really: what if there are lots of lines in the string? That would create heaps of unnecessary strings, if all you want to do is add one line. (And that's not how you'd create the ArrayList: `new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(str.split("\n")))`).

Comment: If there are many lines, OP should not be storing as a string in the first place...

Comment: Thanks! And when i want to add a new line befor the first line should be this:
this.string= newstring + "\n" +this.string;
or not?

Comment: @Gabesz07 Yes, that is probably the best way to do it.

Answer (score -1):

You may use `String.format`.

```
String main = "line1\nline2\n%sline4";
String sub = "line3\n";
String result = String.format(main, sub);
```